# Hiding keyboard on didHideSearchResultsTableView messes up search view

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

- After creating a search display controller which worked great on `iOS7`.
- I am having difficulties to `hide` `keyboard` properly on search view on `iOS8`.
- The results are cut down at the bottom, and the alphabetic section indexer (on the right) is vertically aligned to the bottom
  (screen shot at the end of the post).

#### Basic setup code:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, ... >

@implementation MyViewController 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchDisplayController *mySearchDisplayController;

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
...
}

-(UITableView*) tableView
{
    if (!_tableView){
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)
                                                  style:self.tableViewStyle];
        _tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource=self;
    }
    return _tableView;
}

-(UISearchBar*) searchBar
{
    if(!_searchBar){
        
        _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,144,0)];
        _searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        _searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        _searchBar.translucent = NO;
        _searchBar.delegate = self;
        _searchBar.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
        _searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;        
    }
    return _searchBar;
}


-(void) initWithTableViewStyle: (int) tableViewStyle
{
    //Set the UITableViewStyle
    self.tableViewStyle = tableViewStyle;
    
    //Be sure the searchBar won't overlap the status bar
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
    
    //Add the subviews to the mainView
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

//Create the views dictionaryy
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"searchBar":self.searchBar,
                                  @"tableView": self.tableView};

//Create the constraints using the visual language format
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|[searchBar]|"
                           options:0
                           metrics:nil
                           views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|[tableView]|"
                           options:0
                           metrics:nil
                           views:viewsDictionary]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[searchBar(==44)][tableView]|"
                           options:0
                           metrics:nil
                           views:viewsDictionary]];
}
```

Now to the interesting part which I believe works differently on iOS7 and iOS8 and causes the issue you can see in the screenshot below:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)searchDisplayController: (UISearchDisplayController *)controller
 willShowSearchResultsTableView: (UITableView *)searchTableView {
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
- (void) keyboardWillHide {
    UITableView *tableView = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
    [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

The selector seemed to do the job in iOS7, but here is the result I get when hiding the keyboard on iOS8:

[image]

The bottom rows are cut (the scroller does not enable scrolling down anymore), and the right section indexer is improperly aligned... How can I make this work in iOS8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see code adding layout constraints for the table view. Maybe they are in the -`(void) initWithTableViewStyle: (int) tableViewStyle` method? Make sure they are set up properly since it looks like you use the same tableView for displaying all data and the search results.

What's really good about UISearchController is that it gives you the opportunity to provide a separate view controller to manage results display. Which 1st decouples your classes and helps clean up the mess that using a single UITableView or two UITableView's in a single controller creates. So you apparently are in this mess so I suggest diving a bit more into UISearchController and creating a separate class for results display. This way you will not have to worry about contentInsets and so on.
Do not use UISearchController the same way as UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: Ivan - sorry, I didn't see your answer. I edited the answer with the initWithTableViewStyle call and the constraints.